# EF 6 Code First Generate Views Null Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I'm trying to generate views, because the performance using Code First is super slow until it caches.  Taking ~10 seconds to load the web page the first time until it caches.  Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when I right click my Context object and try to Generate Views.  The error I'm getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  I assume I'm missing something.  Here is my context code, let me know if you want to see my Entities as well:

```
public class BulletinBoardContext : DbContext
{
    public BulletinBoardContext() : base("BulletinBoardContext")
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BulletinBoardContext"].ConnectionString;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Do you mean when you're trying to generate ASP.NET MVC views?

Comment: @gunr2171, it doesn't give me a line, that's all it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  So I assume that's why I'm missing something

Comment: @Tim, No.  Not MVC Views, pre-generated mapping EF views for performance reasons.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469601.aspx

Thanks for both of your responses.

Comment: @Rounder, try pressing Ctrl + Alt + E, then checking "Thrown" under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". You might discover your error location then.

Comment: Are you using EF Power Tools to generate views?

Comment: Ah ok, I don't use EF power tools so I didn't know about that menu item. That was my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BulletinBoardContext"].ConnectionString;
```

This solves the whole problem. It is without any sense as passing connectionStringName to base constructor as you do in your code should already properly assign connection string.

Comment: after view generation, can we add the connection string setting back? if not then where is it supposed to be?

Comment: this line:  : base("BulletinBoardContext") already sets the connection string so there is no need actually to set it again. Usage of base class constructor for that is much simpler.